# How do I Calculate the area of polygons in the checkerboard image in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, polygon

Please guide me to write the program in MATLAB.

I have a checkerboard image. Each square of the chess board has given a number (index number).
On this image, a series of parallel lines are drawn.

How do I calculate the area of ​​each square of the chess board that is located within the parallel lines?

Comment: Is this a homework problem? What are your current attempts to solving it yourself? Where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Well.. What do you mean polygons? They are all squares.
Anyhow, the code is :

```
function CalculateAreas()
   I = logical(checkerboard(20));
   B = bwlabel(I,4);
   props = regionprops(B,'Area');
   disp([props.Area]);
end
```